# Asp.Net 5 Custom DelegatingHandlers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, requesthandler

I have written a custom `DelegatingHandler` that intercepts requests and authenticates it against an API key. This was being used in a WebApi service, pre ASP.NET 5.

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var apiKey = string.Empty; //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("apiKey");

    if (request.Headers.GetValues("Auth").FirstOrDefault() == apiKey)
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    var error = new HttpError("Unauthorized.");
    var response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, error);


    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

I need to be able to use this same handler in a new ASP.NET 5 WebApi service. Will these types of handlers still work or do I have to rewrite it to fit the new framework? If not, how on Earth do I reference it?

Comment: My Asp.Net5, do you mean asp.net core? Just trying to clear up any confusions.

Comment: Im using a .Net CORE project and only utilizing the .Net 4.5.1 framework.